# One to many relationship with multiple tables in using Eloquent ORM in Laravel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-5

I have three Models User, Email and Phone and database tables Users, Emails and Phones with the columns mentioned below.

```
  User: id, name
  Emails: id, user_id, emails
  Phones: id, user_id, phones
```

Right now I am using the following function in User Model to make User relationship with Email and Phone using Eloquent ORM One to Many Relationship

```
public function profile(){
  $data = array();
  $data['emails'] = $this->hasMany('App\Email');
  $data['phones'] = $this->hasMany('App\Phone');
  return
}
```

I want to know that it is necessary to use hasMany() method twice or there is any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should define the relationships separately:

```
public function emails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Email');
}

public function phones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Phone');
}
```

This allows you to query a user like that:

```
$user = User::with('emails')->with('phones')->find($userId);
```

You can take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) for the documentation.

Comment: @AhmarArshad Just FYI, you don't need to call `with` twice. You can combine them to be `with('emails', 'phones')`.

Comment: To clarify, this answer is advising using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this that way too:

```
$user = User::find($userId)->load('emails', 'phones');
```

I think "load's" use is more appropriated in your situation.